# C : Search functionality in Linked List

Tags: c, file, linked-list

I have two linked lists.

```
typedef struct node
{
   char value[256];
   struct node *next;
} Node_t;

    typedef struct node1
    {
       char value1[256];
       int count;
       struct node1 *next;
    } Node1_t;
```

both linked list having data, I want to compare data between two linked lists, which data are common, is there any way to find similar data between two linked list?

Thanks.

Comment: The most obvious way is to traverse each element in the first list, and compare it with each element in the second list.

Comment: @Aziz: Can you please give me example?

Comment: http://www.c.happycodings.com/Data_Structures/code27.html

Comment: @Aziz : Not helpful. I want to compare two linked list and find the witch data are not available in second list.

Comment: why do you have two different node types ifthey are structurally equivalent?

Comment: If your lists aren't sorted already, then sorting them lets you go from O(n^2) to O(n log n) complexity (n log n for the sort, O(n) for the final traverse).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both lists are sorted, then you can use the following algorithm (pseudo-code, runtime complexity `O(n+m)`):

```
INPUT: list1, list2 (first nodes of the lists you want to compare, sorted!)

while list1 != null AND list2 != null
    if list1->value < list2->value
        list1->value = list1->next

    elseif
        list2->value < list1->value
          list2->value = list2->next

    else
        list3->appendValue(list1->value)
        list1->next
```

If one of the lists isn't sorted, you have to compare each element from the first list with each element in the second list (runtime complexity `O(n*m)`):

```
INPUT: list1, list2 (first nodes of the lists you want to compare)

while list1 != null
    list2temp = list2

    while list2temp != null
        if list1->value == list2temp->value
            list3->appendValue(list1->value)
        list2temp = list2temp->next
    list1 = list1->next
```

It's often better to sort the lists first and then use the first method, this will result in a runtime complexity of `O(n log n + m log m)`.
In both cases `list3` will contain the common elements of both lists.

Comment: (or you can sort the list(s) and use the first method. Lower complexity)

Comment: @blueshift: I guess OP isn't interested in complexity at the moment, but I added your comment to the answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Zeta: Thanks for reply, I am using 2nd pseudo-code, but getting error "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type" when i checks the if list1->value == list2temp->value, can you please convert this block to C program?

Comment: that depends on what is your intention to compare. (is 'aaa' equivalent to 'aAa'? or is it not), that only you can decide. strcmp() vs strcasecmp().

Answer (score 2):

```
list = head;
while (list) {
  list1 = head1;
  while (list1) {
    if (yourcompare(list->value, list1->value) == 0) {
      // do something with common data
      // if only possible case: then break;
    }
    list1 = list1->next;
  }
  list = list->next;
}
```

you may add a bookkeeping data like 'short updated' if a once matched value in list1 should not match again. so you need a 'if (! list1->updated) {...; list1->updated = TRUE;}' inside the inner while.

Comment: yourcompare() is a synonym for the compare-function you need to write to compare the two data for equality. it shoul return a 0 for equal and +1 or -1 if value1<value2 or value1>value2. This may be strcmp(), but it may also be a self written soundex()-function for vocally equal like 'I' and 'Ay'.